# Ubuntu 16.04 PXE Netboot PreSeed Install

Tags: ubuntu, pxe

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 via PXE. I'm serving the CD from TFTP/HTTP. I've verified that HTTP files are serving and that that NFS sub-directories are mountable . My problem is that when I select the option to Install the boot goes fine however I'm stuck with the a manual install rather than an automated one. I can go thru all of the steps and install Ubuntu as-is but my preseed file is ignored entirely.
Here's my pxelinux.cfg:

```
path pxe/ubuntu/16.04/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/
default pxe/ubuntu/16.04/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 0
LABEL Ubuntu 16.04
    MENU LABEL Install Ubuntu 16.04 - Automatic
    KERNEL pxe/ubuntu/16.04/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    INITRD pxe/ubuntu/16.04/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz \
    APPEND auto=true priority=critical vga=788 file=pxe/ubuntu/16.04/preseed/default.seed \
    preseed/interactive=false
```

Here's my preseed file:

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string test
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i passwd/root-password password r00tme
d-i passwd/root-password-again password r00tme
d-i passwd/user-fullname string Ken
d-i passwd/username string ken
d-i passwd/user-password password insecure
d-i passwd/user-password-again password insecure
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string time.nist.gov
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect lamp-server
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

How do I get the preseed file to be recognized here so that the install is automated and requires no additional questions?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://serverfault.com/questions/682245/debian-preseed-cfg-language-not-set , a preseed file not set up in the initrd will only be loaded after localization values are set.  You need to set the following in the syslinux.cfg or pxelinux.cfg file first:

```
APPEND url=http://localhost/preseed/desktop.seed vga=normal \
initrd=ubuntu- installer/amd64/initrd.gz \ 
locale=en_CA.UTF-8 console-setup/ask_detect=false  \
console-setup/layoutcode=us keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us \ 
mirror/http/mirror=ca.archive.ubuntu.com netcfg/get_hostname=
```

Adding DEBCONF_DEBUG=5 to the APPEND line will also give you more detailed logs in syslog while you are running the installation.  You should also change the mirror to one suitable to your location.  I also think the **file=** directive is going to look on the client machine for the file - not on the pxe server since it is a boot option passed to the client machine.  You can verify whether the install sees the file by checking /var/log/syslog during installation on the client with DEBCONF_DEBUG turned on.  You'll see "preseed/file doesn't exist" in the log if the install doesn't find it.